# python default argument syntax error

Tags: python, pygame

I just wrote a small text class in python for a game written using pygame and for some reason my default arguments aren't working. I tried looking at the python documentation to see if that might give me an idea what I did wrong, but I didn't fully get the language in the documentation. No one else seems to be having this issue.

Here's the code for the text class:

```
class Text:
    def __init__(self,screen,x_location='center',y_location='center',writeable,color,size=12):
        self.font = pygame.font.Font("Milleni Gem.ttf", size)

        self.text = self.font.render(writeable,True,color)
        self.textRect = self.text.get_rect()

        if x_location == "center":
            self.textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
        else:
            self.textRect.x = x_location

        if y_location == "center":
            self.textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery
        else:
            self.textRect.y = y_location
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        screen.blit(self.text,self.textRect)
```

and here's the code to call it:

```
from gui import *
Text(screen,75,75,currentweapon.clip)#currentweapon.clip is an integer
```

The error I get is this:

```
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

and points to the `def __init__()` line in the code. What does this error mean and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It means exactly what it says: in the list of arguments, you have a non-default argument that follows a default argument, and this is not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def __init__(self,screen,x_location='center',y_location='center',writeable,color,size=12):
```

You have defined non-default arguments after default arguments, this is not allowed. You should use:

```
def __init__(self,screen,writeable,color,x_location='center',y_location='center',size=12):
```

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that had to be done. Thanks! What is the purpose for this? As in, why is it required that default argument variables come after non-default variables?

Comment: @bspymaster: Because the ones with defaults are optional, so it becomes impossible to know in your example which variables were actually intended to pass in.

Comment: Because there would otherwise be no way to know, for example, when you call `Text(screen,75,75,currentweapon.clip)`, whether the first `75` should override the default for `x_location`, or supply a value for `writeable`, or just what.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks! But then how would the code know if I did `Text(screen,"hi",black,75)` which argument `75` is replacing?

Comment: You can put the `size` before `x_location` or call like this `Text(screen, 'hi', black, size=75)`. @bspymaster