# How to randomize sprite image?

Tags: python

I'm having another problem with the game I'm making, I want the Asteroids sprite to be randomized every time I new asteroid is created by the spawner class, but I keep getting this error 'non-default argument follows default argument', and I'm pretty much stumped on what to do, The actual randomized image is stored inside the spawner and is then imported to the Asteroid class. Any help would be greatly appreciated, the images list is a global variable.

```
images = [games.load_image("asteroid_small.bmp"),
      games.load_image("asteroid_med.bmp"),
      games.load_image("asteroid_big.bmp")]

 def check_drop(self):
    """ Decrease countdown or drop asteroid and reset countdown. """
    if self.time_til_drop > 0:
        self.time_til_drop -= 0.7
    else:
        asteroid_size = random.choice(images)
        new_asteroid = Asteroid(x = self.x,image = asteroid_size)
        games.screen.add(new_asteroid)
```

And then this is the part of the asteroid class that the randomized image will be stored in

```
def __init__(self, x, y = 10,image):
    """ Initialize a asteroid object. """
    super(Asteroid, self).__init__(image = image,
                                x = x, y = y,
                                dy = Asteroid.speed)
```

Comment: Can you show Asteroid.__init__?

Comment: Whenever you are trying to determine a problem with an error on StackOverflow, make sure you post the full stack trace.

Comment: I've added the Asteroids __init__, for some reason I double pasted the same bit of code twice, it's been a long day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python default argument syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893820/python-default-argument-syntax-error)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't with how you instantiate the asteroid, it is how you define it:

```
def __init__(self, x, y = 10,image):
```

If you look, `image` is last, after y, which has a default argument. In Python you cannot do such things. You have two options:

```
def __init__(self, x, y = 10, image = None):
    # default the argument to some sentinel value
    # Test for sentinel and the reassign if not matched.
    image = image if image else random.choice(images)
```

or

```
def __init__(self, x, image, y = 10):
    # re-order your arguments.
    # Also note that image, x, y might be a better order 
    # (@see comment by Micael0x2a)
```

Comment: Doing `def __init__(self, image, x, y=10):` might be more clear, since you keep the coords together.

Comment: Thank you! Python is my first programming language and I'm still getting use to understanding everything, or maybe I'm just incredibly stupid

Comment: @user2855453 - don't worry about it. Everybody has to start from somewhere, and this is one of those things you just simply have to memorize. As a general guideline, keyword arguments are like optional arguments, and optional things typically tend to go at the end, especially in programming.